# How to "run" "execute""initiate" .py file in shell

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu

I am new to Linux and python. I downloaded a .py file I am trying to "run" it. I did "./ filename" every time I do that it opens a gedit screen showing me all the innards(code) of the file.

Comment: Did you type `./ filename`, as you said, or `./filename` ?

Comment: Yes I types ./ (space) filename...I also  looked on this site and this question does not seems to have an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong, because there is not supposed to be a space there.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a scripting language, so it needs an interpreter in order to 'execute' the script.

To execute the script can be done via the [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/349420). To use the shebang you must make the file executable:

```
$ chmod +x your-script.py
```

Then you can call it normally from your command line:

```
$ ./your-script.py
```

or calling the interpreter 'manually':

```
$ python your-script.py
```

I'm assuming the script is in the current directory

Comment: the file has a shebang in it already. That's why I'm so confused. Is this "interpreter" something I need to download from somewhere?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python import 
import sys
import dbus
import uuid
import urllib2
import httplib
import getpass  these are the first 10 lines of the file...also this site is awesome I did not think someone would responded...especially that quick.

Comment: your linux machine has the python interpreter included. In the command line try this: python -c "print 'Hello World'"

Comment: the terminal went into this ">" and does not respond to "quit()" "end" "kill" or anything else. I just do not understand why when I "run" the program it does not pop up as it would on a mac or pc. This gedit showing the code but it doesnt actually "RUN" the program.

Comment: If your terminal went to ">" is because is still interpreting and waiting for something, perhaps you missed the second double-quote. Copy-paste exactly all the command: python -c "print 'Hello World'"
To properly exit the interpreter you should hit ctrl+D.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. So what happened is that is spit out Hello World. and went back to the normal  shell beginning line.

Comment: Any idea on why the .py file Idown loaded will not ( or I don't know how to ) "run" also is that even the right terminology In mac I double click something I have downloaded and it opens a dmg...then i click the dms to "run" this program. how do I do that here?

Comment: Your question was about how to run your script. Did my answer work? What did happened? The problem on how your linux GUI associate your python scripts is a completely different issue, Stack Overflow is about precise questions not a broad online tutorial/forum to solve all your questions. See this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I thought my question was pretty specific. How can I get my "script" to work.  I have done all of what you said before I asked the question. S.O was my last opinion. I repeated these step  when you mentioned them. The exact same thing happens. It opens a "getit" window only showing the code...it never actually does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Edit your original question adding all the steps (and screnshots) on what you are doing and what happen if you did one or another thing. If this is posible give more information on what your trying to do, the url of the script.  Is impossible to us to figure out what is happening in your machine without exact steps to reproduce and your current configuration.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you I really appropriate I found a Youtube video barried on the net about my issue. Also How can I get my question back to "0" The downvoter says that it already had an answer but in fact, this was not the case.